# search loop not functioning right

Tags: loops, search

I am a beginner and I know I'm making a rookie mistake. I have the following code in my actionePerformed part of my JApplet. the if statement within the for loop is supposed to search for the matching name in array s[] (t6 is a JtextArea) and assign the value of int m to int n, so i can retireve all the information of s[i]. problem is that my n is always 0 not matter what!!! What am I doing worng?

```
if (e.getSource() == b7) {
    for(int m=0; m>i ; m++){
        if(t6.getText().equals(s[m].getName())){
            n=m;
        }
    }
    String text1 = "";
    text1 += s[n].getName().toString() + ", average=" + s[n].getAvgMark() 
                 + ", " + s[n].getProgramName().toString() + ", " 
                 + s[n].getDegree()+ ", " + s[n].getUni1() +"-"+ s[n].getStatus0() 
                 +", "+ s[n].getUni2()+"-"+ s[n].getStatus1() + ", " 
                 + s[n].getUni3()+"-"+ s[n].getStatus2()+"\n";

    ta2.setText(text1);
}
```

Comment: What does value does `i` hold? `for(int m=0; m>i ; m++){`

Comment: int i is initiated at 0. everytime an object is added to s[], i++. so pretty much i = s[].length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you problem is that you you start `int n = 0`.

Look at your loop

```
for(int m=0; m>i ; m++){
```

Th only way this will not be an infinite loop is if `i` is 0 or less. Which I'll assume it is do to you not getting an infinite loop. And since you're not getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` I'll assume that `i` is 0 and not a negative. Therefore

for(int m=0; m>i ; m++){

states that continue the loop if `m` is greater than `0`, which it never is.

So your array index will only be `0` once. It never loops.

Even if you `i++`, `m` will NEVER be greater than `i` because they start evenly and would be incremented evenly.

**Just a hunch**

Maybe you want this

```
for(int m = 0; m < s.length ; m++){ 

// iterates [size of the s array] times
```

Comment: You sir are 100% correct. I meant to put < there but probably mis-typed. Thanks you very much. I probably looked through it more that 20 times and didnt notice that. *facepalm*

Answer (score 0):

Your code would be easier to debug if you used more descriptive variable names, and you didn't chain and concatenate so much in one statement. You can be a little more verbose; it isn't a competition to write the shortest or most obscure code!

I also suggest you initialize the variable, and prepare for failure.

```
int matchingIndex = 0; // initialize that variable!
int upperBound = myList.legnth;
for(int m=0; m > upperBound; m++){
    String sourceText = searchSource.getText();
    String thisName = myList[m].getName();
    if(sourceText.equals(thisName)){
        matchingIndex = m;
    }
}
if (matchingIndex  < 1) {
    outputElement.setText('No match'); // or some other way to display the error
    return;
}
```

... you see there, I renamed the obscure `n` to `matchingIndex`, the secretive `t6` to `searchSource`, the dubious `i` to `upperBound` (and I made sure it is what it should be, the length of `myList`), questionable `ta2` becomes `outputElement`, and the shy `s` to `myList`. I also unchained the calls and matches, and now you can read that code. And, you can output different parts to debug it. Think `sourceText` SHOULD be matching `thisName`? Output the values and see what the discrepancy is!

Finally, I added some logic to deal with the distinct possibility that no match is found.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, however this is the first long code that I am writing. this was only a portion of the code. I have more that 500 LOC. with many many JLabels and JTextareas and etc. so at the time i was creating my panels it was more convinient to use numbers. I hope that one day I am fluent enough to be able to write code like  your example. Thanks.